# Celery task id in task_revoked handler

Tags: python, django, celery, djcelery

So I have a task that creates a work directory and does all its work there.
The task is called from **server A** and executed on **worker servers**.

I need to make sure the work directory is deleted once the task is done/**canceled**.

I added a task revoked handler and it looks like this:

```
@task
def my_task(value):

    task_id  = current_task.request.id
    work_dir = os.path.join(BASE_WORK_DIR, task_id)
    os.makedirs(work_dir)

    try:
        # Do work...
    finally:
        shutil.rmtree(work_dir)


@task_revoked.connect(sender=my_task)
def my_task_revoked_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    # FIXME: delete work_dir

    print args
    # ()

    print kwargs
    # {'terminated': True, 'signal': <Signal: Signal>, 'expired': False, 'sender': <@task: myapp.core.tasks.my_task>, 'signum': '15'}
```

My problem is when **server A** cancels the task I cannot issue a cleanup of the work directory in the revoked handler since it doesn't have the task_id.

**Is there any way to get the task id from this specific signal handler?**
Some [other Signals](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#task-signals) have them, and I've looked at the source to where these are issued and for some reason this Signal isn't provided with the task_id.

The provided `sender` task contains a trace_task function: `{'__trace__': <function trace_task at 0x3ee8230>}` but I can't see how I could use it since the function itself requires a task_id.

Any other ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening here is you're using an older version of celery that doesn't have support for this first "request" argument.

The upstream issue that added this was [1]; prior to that, I think that you're out of luck and there is no way to get the task_id unfortunately.

[1] https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1555

Comment: Late is better than never I guess =)